# Data from database to JTable

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

i want to fill a table with data by database, i have 2 class in the project, and in the second class have createANDShowGUI method, i want to call this method in top (Mozijegy) class, my methods is called in `public Mozijegy()` i tried to call in public Mozijegy() but the program didnt see my createANDShowGUI method

```
package mozijegy;

public final class Mozijegy extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public Mozijegy() {
        conn = ConnectDB();
        menu();
        foglalas();
        arlista();
        szekfog();
        comboitem();
    }

    public Connection ConnectDB()

    public void comboitem()

    public void menu()

    class tablafeltoltes extends JPanel {

        private boolean DEBUG = false;
        static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
        static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://FARKAS-PC;databaseName=Mozi;integratedSecurity=true;";
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

        public tablafeltoltes() {
            super(new GridLayout(1, 0));
            Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
            columnNames.add("Név");
            columnNames.add("Mennyiség");
            columnNames.add("Kiszerelés");
            columnNames.add("Ár");
            String query = "select Név, Mennyiség, Kiszerelés, Ár from Arlista";
            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Vector<String> vstring = new Vector<String>();
                    vstring.add(rs.getString("Név"));
                    vstring.add(rs.getString("Mennyiség"));
                    vstring.add(rs.getString("Kiszerelés"));
                    vstring.add(rs.getString("Ár"));
                    vstring.add("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                    data.add(vstring);
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (stmt != null) {
                    try {
                        stmt.close();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    }
                }
            }
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
            final JTable table = new JTable(model);
            table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            add(scrollPane);
        }

        private void printDebugData(JTable table) {
            int numRows = table.getRowCount();
            int numCols = table.getColumnCount();
            javax.swing.table.TableModel model = table.getModel();
            System.out.println("Value of data: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
                System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
                for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  " + model.getValueAt(i, j));
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }

        public void createAndShowGUI() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Database Data");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            tablafeltoltes newContentPane = new tablafeltoltes();
            newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
            frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public void main(String[] args) {
            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mozijegy /*mozijegy*/ = new Mozijegy();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what problems are you facing with this task? - Just giving us the requirement does not help us to answer your question. You also need to provide to some text as to what you have tried, and what is giving you problems. What should happen, and what actually is/isn't happening

Comment: "i want to call this method in top (Mozijegy) class" i wrote, i want to call createandshowgui method(this method in tablafeltoltes class) in mozijegy class if can

Comment: Your class is already a JFrame. Don't create another one inside the `createAndShowGui()` method. In fact, just get rid of the `createAndShowGui()` and put everything into your constructor `Mozijegy()`, then just instantiate the class with your constructor in the `main`